# OS X 10.11, El Capitan, regularly almost freezes when Safari is open

Tags: macos, safari

On OS X 10.11, El Capitan, Safari regularly almost freezes. It usually happens on the same sites: Gmail and YouTube. I have to kill Safari and sometimes I even have to reboot the system.

Sometimes it happens when I have too many tabs open and closing them helps (it takes about 10 seconds per tab thanks to freeze).

I am not sure that the problem is in safari because I had the same problem with Chrome (once or twice, cannot really tell as I do not use it often).

So, basically I know nothing about the problem and have no idea how to solve or analyse it. I saved screenshot of `top` output in one of the "bad moments", so maybe someone can find out the cause?

```
top -o cpu
```

[image: top -o cpu]

It looks like something is wrong:

- the amount of faults
- the number of stuck threads
- the percentage of `kernel_task` command (it goes up to 90%)
- 29M of free memory...

Any ideas? It happens regularly but I cannot reproduce it consistently.

Sorry for bad English and poor description of the problem.

Comment: Check Activity Monitor to see if anything is not responding. I often have issues with Flash Player freezing in Safari, causing the whole browser to freeze until I kill Flash.